# How much does the media influence a girl or boy thinking they are not straight?

Tags: development

I believe that to be respectful to all types of sexually the media, advertising, television series and the like have story lines that include gay couples, men and women, some with children, interracial couples and on from there. Watch Disney and you will find story lines with young teens in girl girl, boy boy relations. So for many teens it seems “trendy” any thoughts?

Comment: "Any thoughts?" Sure. Welcome to the site. This is a question-and-answer site, and we require questions to be objectively answerable in a way that a prompt for discussion isn't. This question is highly likely to be closed for that reason, but if you edit it to have an objectively answerable question, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Having a non-traditional sexual orientation is a perfectly normal part of life as is being "non-white" or "non-Christian", etc. As such the media just reflects reality.

Good numbers are hard to come by but maybe 5% or so of the population is "non-straight". The current scientific consensus is that this is mostly "hardwired": just like some people are left handed, some people are LGBT.

Media exposure probably plays only a minor role in influencing someone's actual orientation. However, it does impact the way society deals with it and how comfortable and safe people are in actually expressing and living with their non-majority orientation.

I'm straight, have always been straight and will always be straight. My best gay friend is gay, has always been gay and will always be gay. No amount of media treatment or exposure will make the slightest difference in our orientations, it's just the way we are.

Comment: "However, it does impact the way society deals with it and how comfortable and safe people are in actually expressing and living with their non-majority orientation." +1 (More if I could!) A good eye-opener.